# Bug in Excel VBE?

Tags: excel, vba

I typed the following statement into the Immediate window of the Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2019 Excel:

```
for i = 1 to 51:if Cells(22,Range("BB:BB").Column + i) = vbNullstring then ? i :next i
```

I received an error message: Compile error Next without For

I cut the if statement out allowing the for next loop to have only ? i in it and it counted to 51 in the immediate window. I pasted the if statement back into its own line in the immediate window and it printed "52". I then pasted the if statement back into the For - Next statement and got the same compile error again. Looks like a compiler problem. Anybody see a syntax error?

Comment: Avoid using `:` and split this into multiple lines, adding the `End If`. It doesn't do you much good to try to cram everything into one line.

Comment: you cannot write a loop in the immediate window without using :

Comment: Code like this works ok in code modules - just not in the immediate window. I tried a few variations and they all fail.

Comment: "for i = 1 to 10:if 1 then ?i:Next i" fails but
"for i=1 to 10:?i:Next i" works OK. So something to do with if  : and the compiler for the immediate window.

Comment: Stop writing a loop in the Immediate Window?

Comment: Side note: this doesn't compile in a module either.